# Android need help to code

Tags: java, android, io, ip, android-studio

I have an I/O device and i'm making an app, that must query the status of input on the device, and to switch on and off the output of the device. If any one can help me please? i need to do it through IP.

```
    public void port11 (View view) {
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.2.66/index.html?o1=1");
}
```

The Above code works but its way to slow, I need something faster, help will be much appreciated.
i'm struggling to get faster speed with out crashing the ui, i would like advice on various paths and codes to achieve faster speeds with out crashing the ui.

Comment: You are getting downvoted because your question lacks information. Please describe the problem more detailed.

Comment: Don't do time-intensive work on the UI thread.

Comment: how do i do that? asynchtask?

Comment: If you gonna down grade me at lest comment why!

Comment: You should look up how to do HTTP requests by API without using the webview. There is absolutely no need for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use http get request and use it with asynchtask if one has more than one button.

```
     public void port01 (View view) {

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        URI website = new URI("http://192.168.2.66/index.html?o0=1");
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```